# How to setup a virtual host when frontend and backend are on same level in root folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, virtualhost

I have following directory structure

```
MyWebsite
    Frontend
    Backend
```

Where `MyWebsite` is a root folder. `Frontend` is the files for the website whereas `Backend` is for the admin panel.

I want to setup a virtual host in such a way that
When user types `http://www.mywebsite.com`, it will be pointed to `Frontend` folder
And when user types `http://www.mywebsite.com/backend`, it will be pointed to `Backend` Folder

As Frontend and Backend folder is in same level under root diretory, i can only make work one at a time (either Front end or Backend) but not both. How can it be done?

Here is my Virtual host so far

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/server/www/MyWebsite/Frontend"
    ServerName www.mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias mywebsite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I used `htaccess` to handle the situation and leaving the virtual host setting as it is. Below is the code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mywebsite.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Frontend/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Frontend/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mywebsite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ Frontend/ [L]
```